# Assembly runtime memory allocation

Tags: assembly, mips

I am working on some MIPS assembly code, and am unsure how to allocate memory during runtime. So far, I've been using the stack or the data segment to store anything I may need, but what if I want something more persistent? To be specific, how do I know what memory address to choose when allocating? How do I know that I'm not overwriting something (e.g.: the stack, or the program instructions)? I can start at `0x0000` but I have no idea what's in that block.

I have read [Assembly memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498373/assembly-memory-allocation), but it doesn't seem to answer this question.

Thanks,

PM

EDIT: I think I may have used the wrong term: by persistent I was referring to something along the lines of malloc() in C.

Comment: What OS are you coding for? Are you doing it on bare hardware?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the memory layout of your architecture (Controller / CPU).

As you are using spim, look for the [spim memory layout](http://www.google.com/search?q=spim+memory+layout).

This will, however, not give you any persistence, I don't think spim has any builtin flash memory.