# Is there a particular place in memory used to store the address of reference?

Tags: java

In my rough understanding, the primitive type variable stores the value directly and the reference stores the location of the objects. When we want to access some objects ,we just need to find the reference and get the address of objects stored in the reference. But the objects has the reference to store its address, who stores the address of reference? Or there is some special ways to access the reference?

Comment: It's the value of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "locate the reference". If you don't have a reference to the object somewhere (even inside some deep hierarchy of objects) then you won't find it and this object will get garbage collected if no one has reference to it.

You can have this reference inside a method (like you can have types like `int`, `short` etc. stored there), in that case it is stored in `stack` (it is a part of the memory available to your application, where method's local variables are stored).

Or you can have this reference stored inside other object, in that case this reference is stored in `heap` (also a part of the memory available to your application, objects created with `new` are stored there).

EDIT:

If you want to know how this object is located using a reference then in Java those implementation details are hidden from the developer, so you don't care how this happens. Internally a reference to a object might contain the address of this object in computer memory (address which is unknown to you). If you write for example a C++ program, then you will be able to see memory addresses of objects you create.

Comment: But by what way my program can identify the reference in heap?

Comment: @deathlee: why would you need to?

Comment: Because in my imagination, if the program can't find the address of the reference , it can't find the address of the object and it can't access the object. I don't know if my understanding is right.

Comment: If you have this reference inside a running method then it is stored in memory area called stack so program can locate it there. And if you don't have a reference to a object inside running method, you may still have a reference to a object which contains a reference to other object which contains reference to the object you want, so your program can still access this reference and the object through other objects and references.

Answer (score 0):

'int a;' The content of the variable 'a' is interpreted as an integer

'Object a;' The content of the variable 'a' is interpreted as an address to an Object

Maybe this will help further: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65281/stack-and-heap-memory-in-java

**EDIT:**

Hm... Maybe your question is: "How can the program knows where the variable 'a' (that references an Object) is located? Where is the reference to the variable that references?"

Well, this is a very good question. I don't know if what I will say is completely correct, but let's go.

A program must allocate memory in the stack by itself. So, at compile time, it already defines what are the addresses it will use. For example:

*int a;
a = 5;*

Let's represent the address chosen to place 'a' as '$AAA' (this is just a representation to make things easier). This would be compiled in something like:

*Put 5 in the address $AAA*

See? The compiled code already knows where 'a' is located: the address $AAA. And whenever in your code you use or set the variable A, what will actually be written in your compiled code is the exact address of A, chosen at compile time.

OK. Now you may ask how the compiler knows what addresses are free to use?

So I read the answer to this: [Assembly memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498373/assembly-memory-allocation).

For what I understood, a "program" (to make things easier) receives a range of memory from the OS and is made to think that it is the full memory. So there is no conflict with other programs and the OS needs to map these "virtual addresses" to the real addresses. As result, the compiler can use whatever address it wants without caring if it is free or not, because the OS will give a "full free memory" to the program.

I hope I have made no big mistakes and that it was your real question.

Comment: @deathlee: After the edit, was this your question?